# Помогите подправить программный код (python)

Tags: python

Условие:Ежемесячная Стипендия студента составляет A р, а расходы на проживание превышает стипендии и становятся В р. в месяц. Рост цен ежемесячно увеличивает расходы на 5%. Составьте программу расчета суммы денег, которою необходимо один раз попросить у родителей, чтобы можно было прожить учебный год (10 месяцев), используя только ЭТИ деньги и стипендию.
Сам код:

```
a = int(input('a: '))
b = int(input('b: '))
for i in range(10):
    S=(b + 0.05*b*i - a)
    print(S)
```

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы вывелась сума, но у меня не получается. Если можно помогите и объясните.

Comment: До цикла сумму нужно обнулить, вывод суммы вывести ЗА цикл, и убедиться, что фраза `ежемесячно увеличивает расходы на 5%`  понята правильно - не подразумевается ли там сложный процент?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input('a: '))
b = int(input('b: '))

s = 0

for i in range(10):
    s += (b + 0.05 * b * i - a)

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
expenses = 100  # затраты
expenses_increase_monthly = 0.05  # увеличение затрат в месяц
income = 80  # доход
period_months = 10  # период расчета

total_sum_needed = 0  # необходимая сумма на весь период

for month in range(period_months):
    increase = expenses * month * expenses_increase_monthly  # на сколько вырастут расходы
    month_expenses = round(expenses + increase, 2)  # расход в этом месяце
    sum_needed = month_expenses - income  # необходимая сумма в этом месяце
    total_sum_needed += sum_needed  # добавим к полной необходимой сумме
    print(f"месяц: {month}; "
          f"затраты: {expenses} + {increase} = {month_expenses}; "
          f"необходимая сумма: {month_expenses} - {income} = {sum_needed}; "
          f"общая сумма: {total_sum_needed}")

    expenses = month_expenses  # если затраты накапливаются, сохраним их

print(total_sum_needed)


месяц: 0; затраты: 100 + 0.0 = 100.0; необходимая сумма: 100.0 - 80 = 20.0; общая сумма: 20.0
месяц: 1; затраты: 100.0 + 5.0 = 105.0; необходимая сумма: 105.0 - 80 = 25.0; общая сумма: 45.0
месяц: 2; затраты: 105.0 + 10.5 = 115.5; необходимая сумма: 115.5 - 80 = 35.5; общая сумма: 80.5
месяц: 3; затраты: 115.5 + 17.325 = 132.82; необходимая сумма: 132.82 - 80 = 52.82; общая сумма: 133.32
месяц: 4; затраты: 132.82 + 26.564 = 159.38; необходимая сумма: 159.38 - 80 = 79.38; общая сумма: 212.7
месяц: 5; затраты: 159.38 + 39.845 = 199.22; необходимая сумма: 199.22 - 80 = 119.22; общая сумма: 331.92
месяц: 6; затраты: 199.22 + 59.766 = 258.99; необходимая сумма: 258.99 - 80 = 178.99; общая сумма: 510.91
месяц: 7; затраты: 258.99 + 90.6465 = 349.64; необходимая сумма: 349.64 - 80 = 269.64; общая сумма: 780.55
месяц: 8; затраты: 349.64 + 139.856 = 489.5; необходимая сумма: 489.5 - 80 = 409.5; общая сумма: 1190.05
месяц: 9; затраты: 489.5 + 220.275 = 709.77; необходимая сумма: 709.77 - 80 = 629.77; общая сумма: 1819.82
1819.82
```